# Comparar dados do txt com dados do Banco de dados

Tags: delphi

Segue o código:

```
procedure TfrmGrid.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 txt: TextFile;
 l,treg,treg2, coo, ccf: integer;
 valortxt, valorbd : double;
 lTemp, valor, dtcompratxt: String;
 dtcompra: TDateTime;
begin
DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
//Add tdcupant
//numcupom = coo
//Cupons
DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT dtcompra, numnf, numcupom, ccf, valor FROM tdcupant');

DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;

DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.SetProvider(DModuleGrid.DataSetProvider1);
DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.Open;

  l:= 1;
  treg:= 0;
  treg2:= 0;

  AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
  Reset(txt);
    while not eof(txt) do
    begin
     Readln(txt, lTemp);
     if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') then
     begin
      inc(treg2);
      dtcompratxt := copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4);
      TryStrToDateTime(dtcompratxt, dtcompra);

      //Comparando valores (Valor do Cupom)

      ShowMessage(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString +' '+
        copy(lTemp,53, 6));
       if  (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString = copy(lTemp,53, 6))
       and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('ccf').AsString = copy(lTemp,47,6))
       and (SameDate(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtcompra').AsDate,
         dtcompra))
       then
       begin
        inc(treg);
        StringGrid1.RowCount := treg+1;
        inc(l);
        //Valor no BD
        StringGrid1.Cells[0,l] := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsString;
        valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
        //Valor no TXT
        StringGrid1.Cells[1,l] := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100);
        valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;

        ShowMessage(FloatToStr(valortxt) + ' ' + FloatToStr(valorbd));
       end;
        //Diferença nos valores
       if not (StringGrid1.Cells[0,l] = StringGrid1.Cells[1,l]) then
        begin
            valor := FloatToStr(valorbd - valortxt);
         if (valor = '') then
           begin
            valor := IntToStr(0);
            StringGrid1.Cells[2,l] := valor;
           end
            else
              StringGrid1.Cells[2,l] := valor;
        end;
     end;
    end;
    ShowMessage('Existem '+ IntToStr(treg2) + ' linhas -E14');
    ShowMessage('Existem '+ IntToStr(treg) + ' linhas');
    CloseFile(txt);
end;
```

Esse código não chega ao segundo `if`, segue o código do segundo `if`, que também se encontra acima:

```
dtcompratxt := copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4);
      TryStrToDateTime(dtcompratxt, dtcompra);

      //Comparando valores (Valor do Cupom)

      ShowMessage(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString +' '+
        copy(lTemp,53, 6));
       if  (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString = copy(lTemp,53, 6))
       and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('ccf').AsString = copy(lTemp,47,6))
       and (SameDate(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtcompra').AsDate,
         dtcompra))
       then
       begin
        inc(treg);
        StringGrid1.RowCount := treg+1;
        inc(l);
        //Valor no BD
        StringGrid1.Cells[0,l] := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsString;
        valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
        //Valor no TXT
        StringGrid1.Cells[1,l] := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100);
        valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;

        ShowMessage(FloatToStr(valortxt) + ' ' + FloatToStr(valorbd));
       end;
```

Esse código não consegue fazer a comparação do dado de um para o outro.

O que eu estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Ignorem os `ShowMessages`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o código que desenvolvi como resposta.

Espero que ajude.

```
procedure TfrmGrid.btnLoadClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 txt: TextFile;
 treg, lreg: integer;
 valortxt, valorbd : double;
 lTemp, valor, dtcompratxt: String;
 dtcompra: TDateTime;
begin
lreg:= 1;
treg:= 0;

AssignFile(txt, frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
Reset(txt);
while not eof(txt) do
begin
 Readln(txt, lTemp);
 if  (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') then
 begin
   dtcompratxt := copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4);

   DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
   DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
   DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT dtcompra, numnf, numcupom, ccf, valor FROM tdcupant');
   //DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('WHERE dtcompra = ' + dtcompratxt + ' AND numcupom = ' + copy(lTemp,53, 6) + ' AND numnf = ' + copy(lTemp, 4, 20) + ' AND ccf = '+ copy(lTemp,47,6) + ';');
   DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;
   DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.SetProvider(DModuleGrid.DataSetProvider1);
   DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.Open;

   if not (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.IsEmpty) then
   begin
     DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.First;
     while not DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Eof do
     begin
       if (copy(lTemp,53, 6) = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString)
       and (copy(lTemp,47,6) = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('ccf').AsString)
       and (StrToDateTime(dtcompratxt) = DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('dtcompra').AsDateTime)
       then
       begin
        inc(lreg);
        //Valor no BD
        valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
        //Valor no TXT
        valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;
        //Diferença nos valores
        if (valorbd <> valortxt) then
        begin
          inc(treg);
         if (valor = '') then
           begin
            valor := IntToStr(0);
           end
            else
            valor := IntToStr(treg);
            Label1.Caption:='Divergências entre valores: '+ valor;
        end;

       end;
       DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Next;
     end;
   end;
 end;
end;
ShowMessage('Existem '+ IntToStr(lreg) + ' linhas de Cupons(E14)');
CloseFile(txt);
CloseQuery;
end;
```

Comment: A falta da indentação no código continua sendo um grande problema, pois hoje, com 92 linhas está fácil de ver onde está o que, mas conforme os sistemas crescem e a lógica se complica, os bugs surgem simplesmente pela falta de organização.

Comment: Por exempolo, `if (valor = '') then` parece estar um nível à esquerda do resto, portanto fora do begin de cima. Qualquer descuido e você fecha um laço no lugar errado.

Comment: tem razão, tenho que trabalhar a parte de identação tambem! Obigado pela atenção novamente @Filipe.Fonseca

Comment: Se resolveu sua questão, peço que por favor marque sua resposta como aceita, para que ela deixe de constar nas perguntas sem respostas.

Answer (score 0):

Acertando a indentação do seu código (importantíssimo) cheguei a algumas conclusões. Seguem:

Primeiro o código:

```
var
  txt: TextFile;
  l,treg,treg2, coo, ccf: integer;
  valortxt, valorbd : double;
  lTemp, valor, dtcompratxt: String;
  dtcompra: TDateTime;
begin
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Close;
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Clear;
  //Add tdcupant
  //numcupom = coo
  //Cupons
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT dtcompra, numnf, numcupom, ccf, valor FROM tdcupant');
  DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.Open;
  DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.SetProvider(DModuleGrid.DataSetProvider1);
  DModuleGrid.ClientDataSet1.Open;
  l:= 1;
  treg:= 0;
  treg2:= 0;
  AssignFile(txt,frmSelection.FileListBox1.FileName);
  Reset(txt);
  while not eof(txt) do
  begin
    Readln(txt, lTemp);
    if (copy(lTemp, 1, 3) = 'E14') then
    begin
      inc(treg2);
      dtcompratxt := copy(lTemp,65,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,63,2)+'/'+copy(lTemp,59,4);
      TryStrToDateTime(dtcompratxt, dtcompra);
      //Comparando valores (Valor do Cupom)
      ShowMessage(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString +' '+
      copy(lTemp,53, 6));
      if  (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('numcupom').AsString = copy(lTemp,53, 6))
           and (DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('ccf').AsString = copy(lTemp,47,6))
           and (SameDate(DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.ParamByName('dtcompra').AsDate,dtcompra)) then
      begin
        inc(treg);
        StringGrid1.RowCount := treg+1;
        inc(l);
        //Valor no BD
        StringGrid1.Cells[0,l] := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsString;
        valorbd := DModuleGrid.ZQuery1.FieldByName('valor').AsFloat;
        //Valor no TXT
        StringGrid1.Cells[1,l] := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100);
        valortxt := StrToFloat(copy(lTemp, 109, 14))/100;
        ShowMessage(FloatToStr(valortxt) + ' ' + FloatToStr(valorbd));
      end;
      //Diferença nos valores
      if not (StringGrid1.Cells[0,l] = StringGrid1.Cells[1,l]) then
      begin
        valor := FloatToStr(valorbd - valortxt);
        if (valor = '') then
        begin
          valor := IntToStr(0);
          StringGrid1.Cells[2,l] := valor;
        end
        else
          StringGrid1.Cells[2,l] := valor;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  ShowMessage('Existem '+ IntToStr(treg2) + ' linhas -E14');
  ShowMessage('Existem '+ IntToStr(treg) + ' linhas');
  CloseFile(txt);
```

Como vemos, o segundo e o terceiro ifs estão dentro do primeiro. Se a condição do primeiro não for satisfeita, não chegaremos aos outros.

Quanto ao que mais pode estar sendo feito de errado, depende da sua lógica, a pergunta se torna um pouco subjetiva.

Comment: Eu pensei da mesma forma tambem, e tentei de um modo mais simpes, @Filipe.Fonseca, retirei os stringGrids e apenas coloquei um label com um contador para me indicar a qtd de divergências entre o `valortxt` e o `valorbd`, então, consegui ter uma base de como realizar o código. Eu postei a resposta, espero que goste.